# How can I get my java program to include uppercase and lowercase characters?

Tags: java

I am trying to include uppercase and lowercase letters for my available characters in my code but I am not sure how to go about this. Can anyone give me some insight?

Following is what I have so far for my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShopSign {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Scanner class//
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // variable to store available characters//
    String availableCharacters;     
    // variable to store proposed message//
    String proposedMessage;
    // variable to keep track if message will make it or not to the sign board//
    boolean flag = true;
    // variable to store the character that remain short//
    char shortCharacter = ' ';
    // variable to store character at current position//
    char temp;                      

    // Prompt for input of available characters//
    System.out.println("Enter available characters:");
    // read available characters
    availableCharacters = input.nextLine();

    // Prompt for input of proposed message//
    System.out.print("Enter proposed message: ");
    // read proposed message//
    proposedMessage = input.nextLine();


    // remove white spaces from the message//
    proposedMessage = proposedMessage.replaceAll("\\s","");

    //check if character it is available//
    for(int i = 0; i < proposedMessage.length(); i++){
        temp = proposedMessage.charAt(i);

        // if character is not the whitespace//
        if(temp != ' '){
            // check if character is available//
            if(availableCharacters.indexOf(temp) >= 0){
                // replace the character to empty string from available characters//
                availableCharacters = availableCharacters.replaceFirst(Character.toString(temp), "");
            }
            // otherwise mark the flag false and break the loop//
            else{
                flag = false;
                shortCharacter = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the appropriate message to the user//
    if(flag){
        System.out.println("The message makes it to the sign board.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("We are short of character "+ Character.toString(shortCharacter) +".");
        }
    input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.  From what I can tell, you read `availableCharacters` from your file, and then you make sure that all non-space characters in your proposed message are present in `availableCharacters`.  So it would seem that your question is answered just by putting the right `availableCharacters` string in the input file.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you hoping to do? After using your code and using `aAbB` for the available letters, I then entered `AaBb` as my proposed message and it outputted "`This message makes it to the sign board.`"

EDIT; If you are looking to only allow ONE of any character (upper-case AND lower-case) you can do:

```
availableCharacters = availableCharacters.replaceFirst(Character.toString(temp).toLowerCase(), "");
availableCharacters = availableCharacters.replaceFirst(Character.toString(temp).toUpperCase(), "");
```

Comment: Well I am just trying to allow any combination of uppercase and lowercase characters.

Comment: Your program already allows both, I tried it myself, as stated in my original response. You can set `availableCharacters = "AaAaAa"` and it'll only remove the first of these characters. It won't remove an 'A' if you choose 'a' and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is not clear, but i have suggestion on your code:

1. don't need check `if(temp != ' ')` because you already cleared space
   char on previous code :

   proposedMessage = proposedMessage.replaceAll("\s","");
2. your code will fail in case proposedMessage contains special
   characters (Example : +\...)

   Need to use Pattern.quote before using replaceFirst :

   ```
   String pattern = Pattern.quote(Character.toString(temp));
   availableCharacters = availableCharacters .replaceFirst(pattern, "");
   ```